# Mongo DB - add date to reference object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using `mongoose` and have two schemas, user and community:

UserSchema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  communities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: CommunityModel }],
}, { timestamps: true });
}
```

Community:

```
const CommunitySchema = new Schema({
  name: String, 
  users: [
    { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }
  ]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

When user joins a community, I want to know when it happened, so I'd like to add a joinedAt or createdAt to each community in the UserSchema. How could I achieve it if it is a reference? Is it possible? And if not, what could be the alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer:
AI solved it for me, here is the correct example:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

interface User {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    communities: Community[];
}

interface Community {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    users: User[];
}

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

const communitySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

// Define the user_communities table using the communitySchema
const userCommunitySchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    community: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Community' },
    joined_on: Date,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

// Use the userCommunitySchema to create the UserCommunity model
const UserCommunity = mongoose.model('UserCommunity', userCommunitySchema);

// Use the userSchema to create the User model, and define a virtual property
// for accessing the user's communities
userSchema.virtual('communities', {
    ref: 'Community',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'user',
    justOne: false,
});

const User = mongoose.model<User>('User', userSchema);

// Use the communitySchema to create the Community model, and define a virtual property
// for accessing the community's users
communitySchema.virtual('users', {
    ref: 'User',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'community',
    justOne: false,
});

const Community = mongoose.model<Community>('Community', communitySchema);
```

The `userSchema` and `communitySchema` are then used to create the `User` and `Community` models, respectively. For the `User` model, a virtual property called communities is defined using the virtual method. This virtual property is used to specify how to populate the `user.communities` property when querying the database. The `communitySchema` also defines a users virtual property, which is used to populate the `community.users` property when querying.